# android XML Getting a Resource ID (integer) from XML

Tags: android, xml, resources

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locations>
<location index="0" asset="@drawable/test1"></location>
</locations>
```

When I parse thru the XML and try to retrieve the ResourceID, it doesn't return

```
int ResourceID = xmlParser.getAttributeIntValue(null, "asset", 0);
```

All other values in XML are being retrieved successfully...what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I figured it out, I'm not wanting to just grab an Int

Instead of

```
int ResourceID = xmlParser.getAttributeIntValue(null, "asset", 0);
```

it's

```
int ResourceID = xmlParser.getAttributeResourceValue(null, "asset", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to use the XML file to get the resource ID of your drawable. At compilation the 'R.java' file is written that contains the mappings between resource id's and actual resources .  To get the resource Id simply use:

```
int test1ResId = R.drawable.test1;
```

Comment: yes I do, I'm loading the bitmaps up when I need them - the design is to get the resource ID from an XML file and then loading a bitmap with it

Answer (score 1):

if you are having the string as 'test1'. The proper way of getting the resource id is

```
getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage);
```

Eg.

```
getResources().getIdentifier("test1","drawable","com.app");
```